# Javascript accessing scope by using bind

Tags: javascript, scope, binding, closures, bind

why this logs 1 and not 2 ? i am trying to pass this scope to initData function but no success. after running init i should trigger iniData but this should refer to the object itself not to a new scope

```
    let startFunction = function (){
        let initData = () => {
            this.x = 2
        }
        return {
            x:1,
            init:initData.bind(this)
        };
    };
    obj=startFunction()
    obj.init();
    console.log(obj.x); // should be 2


update:

    let startFunction = function (){
    let initData = function(){
        this.x = 2
    }
    return {
        x:1,
        init:initData
    };
};
    obj=startFunction()
    obj.init();
    console.log(obj.x); // should be 2
```

and why this works ? shouldn't the function create a new scope ?

Comment: `x` in the returned object has nothing to do with the `this.x`. Is there a reason you are avoid using a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here. The first issue is that arrow functions are immutably bound to their execution context. `Function.prototype.bind` has no effect on an  arrow function. The second issue here is what `this` refers to when you call `startFunction`. When you invoke a function freely, without a binding to a particular object, `this` refers to the object in which the function is invoked. So `this` refers to the global object in `initData` permanently.

So let's think about the value of `obj` and the global object's `x` value after each line.

After `obj=startFunction`:

```
// global x is undefined

// obj
{
  x: 1,
  init: initData // with the same binding to the global object
}
```

After `obj.init()`, initData sets the global object's `x` value to 2:

```
// global x is 2

// obj
{
  x: 1,
  init: initData // with the same binding to the global object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem you are facing is the x in the object has nothing to do with the this.x that is being assigned in the init method. You need to set an object and in the init code adjust that object.

```js
let startFunction = function() {

  const initData = () => {
    data.x = 2
  };
  
  var data = {
    x: 1,
    init: initData,
  };
  
  return data;

};

const obj = startFunction()
obj.init();
console.log(obj.x);
```

Better solution, use a proper class.

```js
class MyClass {
 x = 1;
 init() {
   this.x = 2;
 }
}

const obj = new MyClass();
obj.init();
console.log(obj.x);


class MyClass2 {
 x = 1;
 constructor() {
     this.x = 2;
 }
}

const obj2 = new MyClass2();
console.log(obj2.x);
```

Comment: The `.bind` is unnecessary in this solution, and it has no effect on an arrow function.

Comment: `let startFunction = function (){
    let initData = function(){
        this.x = 2
    }
    return {
        x:1,
        init:initData
    };
};
obj=startFunction()
obj.init();
console.log(obj.x); // should be 2`